# How does DKfindout.com (website) annotate the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, annotations

Here is [An example in DKfindout](https://www.dkfindout.com/us/animals-and-nature/fish/what-is-fish/).
I'm wondering how to make **predefined annotation** (not user-defined annotation, e.g. drag a box and add comment) on images.
[image: A screenshot of the example]

I have no idea how to locate the place where I want to add an explanation.
Is there any javascript library can do this job?
Or I have to find the relative position of the annotation of the image (e.g. left:10%, top:10%), then add all annotations one by one?
Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe they're using https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/